# Union of Connected Sets and Transfinite Induction

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, connectedness, transfinite-induction

Recall the following theorem:

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $\{A_\alpha\}$ be a collection of connected subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha\neq\emptyset$. Then $\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha$ is a connected subset of $X$.

I solved the following exercise (Exercise 2 page 152 of Munkres' *Topology*):

> **Exercise**
>
> Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of connected subsets of $X$ such that
>   $$
> \forall n\in\mathbb{N},A_n\cap A_{n+1}\ne\emptyset.
> $$
>   Show that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ is a connected subset of $X$.

After that, I attempted to generalize the result using transfinite induction. Could you please verify if my proof is correct, or tell me if there are any improvements? Thank you in advance.

> **Generalization**
>
> For any nonzero ordinal $\alpha$, we have the following:
>
> "Let $\{A_\beta\mid\beta\in\alpha\}$ be a collection of connected subsets of $X$. Suppose that 
>   $$
> \forall\beta\in\alpha,A_\beta\cap A_{\beta^+}\ne\emptyset
> $$
>   and that for any limit ordinal $\lambda\in\alpha$, there exists $\beta\in\lambda$ such that $A_\lambda\cap A_\beta\ne\emptyset$. Then $\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha}A_\beta$ is a connected subset of $X$."

*Proof*. For any $\beta\in\alpha$, define

$$
B_\beta=\bigcup_{\gamma\underline{\in}\beta}A_\gamma
$$

We prove using transfinite that all the $B_\beta$ are connected. Let $\beta\in\alpha$ and assume that for every $\gamma\in\beta$, $B_\gamma$ is connected.

- $\beta=0$: $B_0=A_0$ is connected.
- $\beta=\gamma^+$: We have
  $$
  B_\beta=B_\gamma\cup A_{\gamma^+}
  $$
  is the union of two connected sets and
  $$
  \left(\bigcup_{\delta\underline{\in}\gamma}A_\delta\right)\cap A_{\gamma^+}\supset A_\gamma\cap A_{\gamma^+}\ne\emptyset.
  $$
  Thus according to the theorem, $B_\beta$ is connected.
- $\beta$ is a limit ordinal: We have
  $$
  B_\beta=\left(\bigcup_{\gamma\in\beta}B_\gamma\right)\cup A_\beta.
  $$
  Using the theorem, $\bigcup_{\gamma\in\beta}B_\gamma$ is connected. Indeed every $B_\gamma$ is connected and 
  \begin{align*}
  \bigcap_{\gamma\in\beta}B_\gamma&=B_0\\
  &=A_0\\
  &\supset A_0\cap A_1\\
  &\ne\emptyset.
  \end{align*}

Therefore for every $\beta\in\alpha$, $B_\beta$ is connected.

Now $\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha}A_\beta=\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha}B_\beta$ where all the $B_\beta$ are connected for $\beta\in\alpha$ and $\bigcap_{\beta\in\alpha}B_\beta=B_0\neq\emptyset$. The theorem ensures the desired result.$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\square$

---

Thank you for your remarks in comments. Here's the new generalization and proof:

> **Generalization**
>
> For any nonzero ordinal $\alpha$, we have the following:
>
> "Let $\{A_\beta\mid\beta\in\alpha\}$ be a collection of connected subsets of $X$. Suppose that 
>   $$
> \forall\beta\in\alpha,\exists\gamma\in\beta,A_\gamma\cap A_\beta\ne\emptyset.
> $$
>   Then $\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha}A_\beta$ is a connected subset of $X$."

*Proof*. For any $\beta\in\alpha$, define

$$
B_\beta=\bigcup_{\gamma\underline{\in}\beta}A_\gamma
$$

We prove using transfinite that all the $B_\beta$ are connected. Let $\beta\in\alpha$ and assume that for every $\gamma\in\beta$, $B_\gamma$ is connected.

- $\beta=0$: $B_0=A_0$ is connected.
- $\beta\neq 0$: We have
  $$
  B_\beta=\left(\bigcup_{\gamma\in\beta}B_\gamma\right)\cup A_\beta.
  $$
  Using the theorem, $\bigcup_{\gamma\in\beta}B_\gamma$ is connected. Indeed every $B_\gamma$ is connected and 
  \begin{align*}
  \bigcap_{\gamma\in\beta}B_\gamma&=B_0\\
  &=A_0\\
  &\supset A_0\cap A_1\\
  &\ne\emptyset.
  \end{align*}

By assumption, there exists $\gamma\in\beta$ such that $A_\beta\cap A_\gamma\ne\emptyset$. In other words,
$$
A_\beta\cap\left(\bigcup_{\gamma\in\beta}A_\gamma\right)\ne\emptyset.
$$
Since $\bigcup_{\gamma\in\beta}A_\gamma=\bigcup_{\gamma\in\beta}B_\gamma$, $B_\beta$ is connected according to the theorem.

Therefore for every $\beta\in\alpha$, $B_\beta$ is connected.

Now $\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha}A_\beta=\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha}B_\beta$ where all the $B_\beta$ are connected for $\beta\in\alpha$ and $\bigcap_{\beta\in\alpha}B_\beta=B_0\neq\emptyset$. The theorem ensures the desired result.$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\square$

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: I guess that by $\beta^+$ you mean the **ordinal** successor, which as far as I know is usually denoted by $\beta+1.$ Doesn't the notation $\beta^+$ usually refer to the **cardinal** successor?

Comment: In the case of $\beta$ a limit ordinal, you haven't even said that $$A_{\beta} \cap \bigcup_{\gamma \in \beta} B_{\gamma} \neq \varnothing.$$ That needs to be done. (And the short proof of that fact needs to be added too.)

Comment: Seems to me you could make it still more general. Namely, instead of assuming that $A_{\beta^+}\cap A_\beta\ne\emptyset,$ you could simply assume that for *every* nonzero ordinal $\lambda\in\alpha,$ whether limit or successor, you have $A_\lambda\cap A_\beta\ne\emptyset$ for some ordinal $\beta\lt\lambda.$

Comment: @AdriánNaranjo Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @bof Thank you for your comment. $\beta+1$ does indeed denote the ordinal successor. In *Elements of Set Theory* by Enderton, $\beta^+$ was another notation for that. That's the only set theory book that I read. The notation isn't standard? That's a nice shortcut :/

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your comment. Your remark is crucial. I forgot to write what you said. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: @bof Yes you are right! It can be generalized that way!

Comment: Does ordinal induction really require all three of these steps (the basis step, the successor step, and the limit step)? Suppose you just did one step, as follows: Suppose the proposition is true of every ordinal less than $\beta$. Then we prove as follows that it is true of $\beta$ [then insert the details of that proof here]. Shouldn't that be enough? It is vacuously true that the proposition holds for every ordinal less than $0$; therefore this given proof shows that its true of $0$ and thus it includes the basis step. It also includes successor and limit ordinals. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for your comment. You could post this as an answer.

Comment: @bof You could also post your remark as an answer.

Comment: @Scientifica : I'm not sure it would make sense as an answer without including the the details that I mentioned in the square brackets.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Feel confortable. Personally I don't mind that, and I believe that an answer doesn't have to include details. What's important is the key idea :)